# Help designing a Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, finite-automata

I am faced with the following question:

> Design a Turing Machine that recognizes the language $L = \{1^{2n+1}\mid n \text{ is a non-negative integer}\}$. Show the state diagram.

I started doing this using $Q \times \Gamma \rightarrow Q \times \Gamma \times \{L, R\}$, and setting up a 7 tuple but I cannot come up with the state diagram.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: What 7-tuple did you get?

Comment: Hint: the idea of homework is for you to do it. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: How would *you* check whether a string belongs to that language? Is that an algorithm? What do you distinguish? Can you see that as states? Or is your problem technical (you don't know how to draw a TM)?

Comment: Dont know how the draw the TM. But thank you for the tips

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $L$ is regular. Draw a DFA accepting $L$, and modify it to a full-fledged Turing machine whose operation is essentially equivalent to that of the DFA.

Comment: Makes sense, will try. What is the conversion process between a DFA and turing machine?

Comment: You'll have to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 2: the "state diagram" and the 7-tuple are two representations of the same idea. One as a drawing, the other as a table..

Make sure you understand what a state diagram means. How can you take a 7-tuple (that you said you know how to get) and convert it into a state-diagram?